# Hearing back after an academic interview in the UK

Tags: job, interview

I had an interview for a lecturer position at a UK Russell group University 2 days ago and haven't heard back yet. From previous experience, I am usually given a call within 24 hours of being successful in an interview. I am holding off signing an offer by another University (not a great University) and being pressured to respond. I really want the first job but feel my chances are getting lower by the day?
I'd like to hear about other experiences and whether this timeline is unrealistic? I work in the field of science, not sure this makes a difference?

Comment: Two days ago? There's been a weekend in between, perhaps people were not at work.

Comment: In your previous experiences you were pretty lucky to hear back so fast. It's quite common to have interviews spread out over different days.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the customs and practices in a particular University, it can take from one to several days before the decision is made, approved, and the first candidate is contacted. "Several days" is typically below a week, but in rare cases can be longer.

If you are not contacted within 2-3 days, you may not be the first candidate. However, there is still a slim chance that the first candidate does not accept (for whatever reason), and the offer goes to you.

If you hold another offer, it is usually the best to let both Universities know the date, when you will make the final decision, based on what you have at this date. Everyone understands that candidates are usually applying in several places simultaneously, and HRs/HoDs can be quite efficient when they must (i.e. if they are interested in hiring you), and inefficient otherwise.

Comment: Thank you @Dmitry, that's very helpful

Comment: @jen To reinforce this: I think it would be entirely reasonable to email the HoD/your contact at the university, saying "I'm holding another offer and need to give them an answer; can you tell me when I'm likely to hear your decision?"

Answer (score 1):

I worked at a Russel group university and was on the hiring committee a few times. Sometimes, we would have interviewed candidates on different days (because of availability). Thus, we had to wait to see all candidates before making an offer. Then, the offer would go to the top candidate and give them some time to answer. If the answer was positive, we would inform the rest of the candidates. If the first candidate rejects, we would move to the second appointable etc. Now with covid and all, things might move slower as well (e.g., candidate/committee availability, etc.)

Comment: I applied to russel group universities, was invited to the interview, was not the first candidate, and was never informed about the decision (in one case) or informed 4+ weeks after the interview (2 cases).

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov Yikes. That's nasty. In my university, as soon as an appointment was made, there was an automatic message to all the rest candidates. A bit impersonal, but better than nothing.